# Random Orange border appearing on android

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue regarding an orange border appearing to me each time I tap on the div of any of the tabs in my `Home.html` page. I am really trying to remove the border by many means but it seems like its not working out. I have tried `outline:none !important` but it didn't work for me but it works in the previous page. I am using bootstrap classes. .. Please if anyone can help, tell me what is the solution for this. Thank you in advance.

```css
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
 color:#FFFF00;
 background-color: #323232;
 border: 1px solid #ffff00;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    outline: none !important;
 }
 .nav-tabs > li > a{
 color:#FFFF00;
 background-color: #323232;
 outline: none !important;
 }
 
 .nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
 background-color: #323232;
      color: #ffff00;
      outline: none !important;
 }
 
 .nav-tabs{
 background-color: #323232;
 outline: none !important;
 }
 
 
 .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus{
  background-color: #323232;
      color: #ffff00;
      border-color: transparent;
      outline: none !important;
 }
 
 
 
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,.dropdown-menu > li > a, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{
  background-color: #323232;
      color: #ffff00;
      border-color: #ffff00;
      outline: none !important;
 }
 
 .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus{
  background-color: #323232;
  color: #ffff00;
  outline: none !important;
 }
```

```html
<!--HTML CODE-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HomePage</title>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
 <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/home.css' />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body onload="loadstring()">

<!-- Nav bar for switching tabs -->
<div class="Homenavbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown1">Dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown2">Dropdown2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
            <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 1</h3>
            <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis. Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 2</h3>
            <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- End nav bar -->

 
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border: 1px solid #ffff00;` from your CSS. This will remove the yellow border around the tab.

```css
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
 color:#FFFF00;
 background-color: #323232;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    outline: none !important;
 }
 .nav-tabs > li > a{
 color:#FFFF00;
 background-color: #323232;
 outline: none !important;
 }
 
 .nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
 background-color: #323232;
      color: #ffff00;
      outline: none !important;
 }
 
 .nav-tabs{
 background-color: #323232;
 outline: none !important;
 }
 
 
 .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus{
  background-color: #323232;
      color: #ffff00;
      border-color: transparent;
      outline: none !important;
 }
 
 
 
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,.dropdown-menu > li > a, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{
  background-color: #323232;
      color: #ffff00;
      border-color: #ffff00;
      outline: none !important;
 }
 
 .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus{
  background-color: #323232;
  color: #ffff00;
  outline: none !important;
 }
```

```html
<!--HTML CODE-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HomePage</title>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
 <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/home.css' />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body onload="loadstring()">

<!-- Nav bar for switching tabs -->
<div class="Homenavbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown1">Dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown2">Dropdown2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
            <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 1</h3>
            <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis. Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 2</h3>
            <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- End nav bar -->

 
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work:

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

More info regarding this you can find here:
https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

Also remove the border you are adding to li elements:

```
border: 1px solid #ffff00;
```

This should be removed ... when you tap the link you put it on `focus` so it adds the border ... remove it and its ok.

Comment: i have no problem with the 1 px solid #ffff00 i made it on purpose what i am talking about is a strange orange border appears whenever i click on the div containing the content of the tab it just makes a very silly orange border around the screen by itself

Comment: Then the outline:0 should fix it for all a elements.

Comment: Does the issue appear only on mobile browsers? Also can you tell us in which browser have you tried and it didnt worked?

Comment: The issue appears when i am running my mobile app and it came to me before and i used this outline thing and it worked but now i wasn't aware that all that time the div focus is making the border not the a elements .. Again thank you so much arber

Comment: I am running normally on my device not on a mobile browser

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aahh7osk/1/ to check the problem ... thought cant test it much on my mobile since its not easy to work with the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution for this random orange border.. all you need to do is to put this in the CSS file

```css
div{
 outline:none !important;
}
```